# How to take dynamic DateTime in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: date, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have 2 asset a credit card type(like Platinum, Gold) and an asset of credit card.
I'll put validity in card type asset as 1 year or according to type and
 when i will create credit card it takes "validfrom" input as the time when the asset is creating and "validTill" parameter by calculating card type's validity and adding them in current date.

```
asset cardType identified by typeId {
  o String typeId  
  o String cardName
  o DateTime validity 
}
```

which datatype should i use?how can i give 1 year kind of parameter in DateTime?

```
asset creditCard identified by cardId {
  o String cardId
  --> cardType type
  o DateTime validityFrom
  o DateTime validityTill
}
```

Is there any 'now' kind of keyword like in Ethereum?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no dynamic default values in the modeling language, only static literal defaults.

You will need to write code to calculate your dates.

For dates, you are recommended to calculate the dates in your calling program, not the Transaction Function - the reason being that in a multi-peer environment the endorsement process has the Transaction executed on multi-peers and the results need to match - using functions like "now" will likely return different results on different peers and your transactions will fail.